# Installing XP or Ubuntu 11.10 results in an "Operating System not found" error

Tags: boot, tablet

I'm trying to install XP and Ubuntu on an RM tablet PC. I'm using an external DVD drive. I've tried installing XP using all of the default options. Got the above error. Booted in to the recovery console and tried fixmbr and fixboot neither made any difference.

I then tried installing Ubuntu with defaul options, got the same error.

In both of the above scenarios I confirmed that the hard drive had the highest boot priority in the BIOS. I tried booting the the external CD drive unplugged and I confirmed that the partition was active.

Any help would be great,

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

You want to install XP first then install UBUNTU it makes it easier. Ubuntu should recognize that XP is installed and try to configure Grub to recognize the Windows Partition.

When it comes down to it GRUB is not pointing correctly to whatever partition is the boot partition for whatever OS you are trying to boost into.

Grub documentation can be found here. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

If GRUB itself does not load you will need to reinstall or reconfigure grub.

Comment: GRUB itself doesn't load. I'm going to try installing LILO or something and see if that makes a difference.